# kubectl get pods by container environment variable

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Can I use `kubectl get pods` with some sort of field selector or selector that supports getting a single pod based upon a container environment variable?

I'd like to get this pod, and only this pod out of thousands and thousands, based upon the value of `ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` with `kubectl`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - env:
    - name: ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE
      value: abc123
    image: my-images
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: my-pod
```

`kubectl get pods --field-selector` no, field is not supported

`kubectl get pods -l` it's not a label

What else can I try, if anything?

Comment: you could try to get your pods' environment variable's value and the pods' names using a jsonpath selector, e.g. `kubectl get pods -o jsonpath="{...}"` https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/

then pipe output and grep for your environment-variable's value: `| grep <value>` - filtering seems to be also possible with jsonpath....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a pod `my-pod` with an environment variable `PORT` with value `8080` like:

```
  metadata:
  ...
    name: my-pod
  ...
  spec:
    containers:
    - env:
      - name: PORT
        value: "8080"
  ...
```

and I can use `kubectl` to filter this pod like:

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces \
-o=jsonpath=\
'{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.spec.containers[*].env[?(@.name=="PORT")]}{"\n"}{end}' | \
grep 8080

output is:

my-pod  map[name:PORT value:8080]
```

So, you can try:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces \
-o=jsonpath=\
'{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.spec.containers[*].env[?(@.name=="ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE")]}{"\n"}{end}' | \
grep abc123
```

Answer (score 2):

via [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)...

By name

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --chunk-size=0 -o json | \
  jq '.items[] | select(.spec.containers[].env[]?.name == "ENVNAME")
               | .metadata.name'
```

By value

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --chunk-size=0 -o json | \
  jq '.items[] | select(.spec.containers[].env[]?.value == "AVALUE")
               | .metadata.name'
```

By name and value

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --chunk-size=0 -o json | \
  jq '.items[] | select(.spec.containers[].env[]? | .name == "ENVNAME" and .value == "AVALUE")
               | .metadata.name'
```

Or there's [API client libraries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/#officially-supported-kubernetes-client-libraries) for most languages. If you add `--v=9` to a `kubectl` command it will output the endpoints it is hitting to gather data. In this case: https://api-server/api/v1/pods